# Create a Download link with user input placed in the middle of link

Tags: html, merge, hyperlink, generate

I wish to generate a download link button with user input replacing certain text in the link it's self.

http://linkhere/folder/foder/folder/InvoiceEnquiry.action?getPDF=&invoiceNumber=(User input result placed here)&criteria.invoiceType=INVOICE

Is this possible. I can use html code to get to the userinput but not to place the final part of the link after it prior to clicking the download button.

```
    HTML Codes online
Form Builder

   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace("First part of link"+inputvalue");

    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

       <input type="text" value="002" id="input"> 
       <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Generated full download link with the users input and the extension of the link placed afterwards to have a complete download link

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need JQuery for this. Vanilla JS would work fine. Just wrap the redirect in a function and call the function with the HTML "onclick" attribute on the button element. Then you can get rid of the JQuery script, unless something else needs it.

Secondly the replace() method takes two arguments. You're giving it one concatenated string (the + operator used in this way is for combining strings).

window.location.replace("(User input result placed here)", inputvalue");

That will work if (User input result placed here) doesn't change.

Comment: That went straight over my head :) Beyond my knowledge sorry

Comment: Its ok, just focus on the second part. It's that syntax error that's causing your issue.